# Jump to search text in Stackdriver Logs Viewer

Tags: google-cloud-logging

When looking for a specific problem in the logs, I will enter a search term in the Stackdriver Log Viewer filter.  However, this is very awkward as I often need to look at previous or subsequent entries. I often have to re-enter a new search specifying a time window or just jumping to the time in question.  And if I want to look for other examples I then have to go through the whole process again which I find very frustrating.

Is there any way to search backwards from my current position until I hit an entered search term?  This would make troubleshooting via the logs far more convenient.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood it correctly, you want to set a starting point for your next search term at a specific point found during a previous search. In that case, you could facilitate your navigation through the logs by pinning a log at the specific moment you want to “fixate” you search on.

According to the [Viewing logs documentation](https://cloud.google.com/logging/docs/view/overview#pin), after you pinned a log, you are free to change the filter and the Logs Viewer will automatically center around the pinned log.

Comment: No, I just want to search for specific text from where I currently am.  This could be just browsing the logs with no filters assigned

Comment: You could still pin entries even if you are not using any filters. Do you want to see logs that are newer or older than the point which you are currently at? Or do you want to be able to search a specific text only from the logs that you are seeing in the Logs Viewer (without loading additional entries)?